# TCP states TCP_CA_Recovery vs TCP_CA_Loss

Tags: sockets, tcp

In a tcp file transfer, when are the differences between the following states ?

TCP_CA_Recovery and TCP_CA_Loss ?!!

and when does the state of the transmission set to these values? Does packet loss leads= to Recovery, Loss or neither?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR** - Recovery is reached when duplicate acks or selective acks are detected. Packet loss leads to `TCP_CA_Recovery` state, which can lead to `TCP_CA_Loss` if retransmission timeout is reached.

Both flags are one of the 5 states of TCP congestion avoidance implementation in Linux.

```
enum tcp_ca_state
{
    TCP_CA_Open = 0,
#define TCPF_CA_Open    (1<<TCP_CA_Open)
    TCP_CA_Disorder = 1,
#define TCPF_CA_Disorder (1<<TCP_CA_Disorder)
    TCP_CA_CWR = 2,
#define TCPF_CA_CWR (1<<TCP_CA_CWR)
    TCP_CA_Recovery = 3,
#define TCPF_CA_Recovery (1<<TCP_CA_Recovery)
    TCP_CA_Loss = 4
#define TCPF_CA_Loss    (1<<TCP_CA_Loss)
};
```

See [here](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/people/marcelo/linux-2.4/include/linux/tcp.h).

Therefore all of the abnormal (non-open) states are steps of recovery after the TCP implementation 'senses' that the link is congested.

- `TCP_CA_Open` - normal state of ACK processing (regulating the congestion window normally).
- `TCP_CA_Disorder` - duplicate ACKs (DUPACKs) or selective acknowledgements (SACKS) detected/received.
- `TCP_CA_CWR` - congestion window reduced state. Linux TCP stack starts to reduce congestion window in this state. This state can be interrupted by `TCP_CA_Recovery` or `TCP_CA_Loss`
- `TCP_CA_Recovery` - state is entered when starting the retransmission of the packets.

> The sender stays in the Recovery state until all of the segments
>   outstanding when the Recovery state was entered are successfully
>   acknowledged. After this the sender goes back to the Open state. A
>   retransmission timeout can also interrupt the Recovery state.

(source mentioned below).

- `TCP_CA_Loss` - State entered when TCP RTO (retransmission timeout) expires.

You can read more about it [here](https://www.cs.helsinki.fi/research/iwtcp/papers/linuxtcp.pdf). And also [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470147733) book.